# PowerShell: $input value changes in function

Tags: powershell

What I have found is that when I write the following function:

```
function test {
    Write-Host ($input | Measure-Object).Count
    Write-Host ($input | Measure-Object).Count
}
```

with sample input:

```
dir | test
```

it writes on the console:

```
18
0
```

I think it is because the first pipe to Measure-Object overwrites $input. I know of a workaround where I would make a new array and pass that around:

```
function test {
    $inp = @($input)
    Write-Host ($inp | Measure-Object).Count
    Write-Host ($inp | Measure-Object).Count
}
```

However I don't like it because I am introducing a new variable.   Is there a way of piping to a cmdlet while leaving $input unaffected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function test {    
 Write-Host ($input | Measure-Object).Count
 $input.reset()
 Write-Host ($input | Measure-Object).Count
}
```

[reading about `$input` enumerator](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/)

Comment: also see http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/

Answer (score 2):

`$input` is an `ArrayListEnumeratorSimple`:

```
C:\Users\roger> $input.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    True     ArrayListEnumeratorSimple                System.Object
```

...which means that it's an enumerator over a sequence of items. Thus, as you consume items in it, you use them up.

I attempted the following:

```
function foo
{
    $input | select -first 3 | % { Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'Red' $_ }
    $input | % { Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'White' $_ }
}
```

...to show that `select -first 3` eats the first 3 items, but it appears to swallow all of them.

Trying the following:

```
function bar
{
    $n = 0
    foreach ($x in $input) {
        if ( ++$n -eq 3 ) { break }
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'Red' $x
    }

    $input | % { Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'White' $_ }
}

dir | bar
```

...shows the difference.

However, since $input is an enumerator (strictly an `IEnumerator`), you can call `Reset()` on it to rewind it.

Note that in .NET-land, not all enumerators can be reset. I'm not sure if there are any scenarios in PowerShell where this is the case with `$input`.